# Best way for communication between MySQL and Java

Tags: java, android, mysql, database

I'm developing a game in Java and I need need store and get data from mysql database.

Currently I have login credentials saved in my Java app source codes and I'm using some library for the communication. But I think that this is a really unsecured way cause of credentials saved in the Java file.

I was wondering what if I do it through some server side PHP scripts which would just get some information and do what is necessary. But again somebody can get that link and do some evil.

I also thought about creating a new database and mysql user for each user registered. So there would be central database where would be just informations for game and it would be read only. So no security problems. And user informations would be saved in his own database and only he would have login for it. But I see one problem, what if I'll need get some information from another user?

So I was wondering what is the best way to keep it simple and secured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a set of services (RESTful will be good) in server side (through PHP or Java or another programming language) that communicates with the datasource (MySQL or another). Then, from your client, consume these services. Now, you can assure the client and server points for communication like authentication and authorization to consume the services, you can use OAuth for this.

> also thought about creating a new database and mysql user for each user registered. So there would be central database where would be just informations for game and it would be read only. So no security problems. And user informations would be saved in his own database and only he would have login for it

This is a **no go**. Since it's a game, you will have to maintain a single database **per user**. It's highly costly and you will have more problems than just retrieving the data from *another user*.

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at OAuth. So I should have one database and one user and I should work with that database through a PHP script on server-side to which client will send Auth credentials and command. Script will handle it and will return some result. Do I get it right?